# Migrating Push Notifications From Parse to Parse-Server

Tags: php, ios, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

My Company has an iOS app which used the old parse.com service to send notifications using a php client. We have since bought a new app but some of our customers have decided to not upgrade to the new platform. What is the simplest way for me to repair the push functionality?

I hope this makes sense. I am a front-end developer usually, with not much experience but this has kind of become my responsibility. One thing to note is I don't actually have access to the native code of the app at the moment. Would I be able to fix this without making any changes to the code of the app?

Comment: What's your old app even connected to now? Did you migrate to parse-server, or is that more the job you're talking about? That is a pretty significant task, and will likely be a little difficult and time consuming for a front end dev. Parse.com is completely gone, so the old app is gonna be caput if you can't get the source code to push an update using your new parse-server URL. The important thing ot have for push in particular, though, is the APNS certs for test and prod. Uploading those and synching device ID info across servers is the bulk of what you need to do for that alone.

Comment: Apologies for the (very) slow reply. 

The app at the moment basically reads from a website. So it pulls in news stories and events from a separate website. It's for schools. When they update their sites the apps updates also. The only thing the Parse service was used for was the push functionality.

So basically when a news story is added to the website cms, as well as adding the data to the SQL database it  also triggered a push notification to be sent to the APP. This is the only functionality I have to fix. I have access to the cms code and I have the APNS, profiles and appids etc.

Comment: I would highly recommend not trying to set that up on parse-server. It'll be a lot of leg work for a feature that was pretty much an after thought to actually include in parse-server. It would likely be beneficial to use a dedicated push notification service. This came up with a quick Google search - looks like they may be able to specifically help migrate parse push notifications: https://www.urbanairship.com/blog/migrating-from-parse-push-notifications

Firebase would be a fair alternative. But, yeah, if you don't actually need to use the rest of parse-server, migrate to another solution.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I kinda thought I might be over complicating it by attempting to migrate to Parse-Server but I couldn't find anything better. I can get stuck into looking at that. Hopefully I find it OK.

Comment: No problem. Wish I could help more with the actual migration, but it's been a minute since I did that haha. I know there was some sort of push export tool, and I had to import that into parse-server.  I imagine the export was a more universal output that could be used by another service.  Good luck!